# Estimation of $\int_{-1}^1(e^{x^3}+e^{-x^3})\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{-1}^1(e^{x^3}+e^{-x^3})\,dx$$

The function $e^{x^3} + e^{-x^3}$ is an even function, so the integral will become $2 \cdot \int_{-1}^1 (e^{x^3} + e^{-x^3})dx$.
So, I estimated its value to be $> 4$ and $< 2(e+\frac{1}{e})$. But answer also includes $\frac{1}{e}+2$ and $<2e$. I'm unable to understand it. Would someone please help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: Really depends on the techniques available to you. The integrand is $2\cosh(x^3)$, so hypothetically you could just go however far you'd like with its series expansion, presumably.

Comment: Please typeset your mathematics with MathJax. For inline equations (i.e., in the middle of a paragraph, rather than set apart from paragraphs), enclose your equation or expression in single dollar signs; for example, `$>4$` gives $> 4$, and `$e^{x^3}+e^{-x^3}$` gives $e^{x^3}+e^{-x^3}$. More [help](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here—possibly more than you might want at first, but at any rate help. :-)

Comment: @PrincessEev: cosh would be $e^{x^3}+e^{-x^3}$, but it is $e^{x^3}+e^{x^{-3}}$. Or is it a typo?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts If you look at the edit history, the $x^{-3}$ was introduced entirely in other contributors' edits.  I've reverted it back.

Comment: Hint: The integral can be done exactly in terms of the incomplete Gamma function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the Maclaurin series of the exponential function, on the interval $[-1,1]$, we have $e^{x^3}+e^{-x^3}\approx 2+x^6$ so $\int_{-1}^1 (e^{x^3}+e^{-x^3})dx\approx \int_{-1}^1 (2+x^6)dx$ which is approximately 4,28.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$I=\int_{-1}^{1} [e^{x^3}+e^{-x^3}]~ dx= 2\int_{0}^{1} [e^{x^3}+e^{-x^3}] dx=4 \int_0^1 \cosh x^3 dx.$$
For $x\in[0,1]$,we have $x^3<x \implies \cosh x^3 \le \cosh x$ and $\cosh x\ge   1$. Hence we have
$$4 \le I< 4\int_{0}^1 \cosh x dx \implies 4 \le I \le 2(e-e^{-1}).$$

Comment: Thanks. But I'm a high school student and have not studied hyperbolic functions yet. Could you please provide another method which would be easier for me to understand.

Comment: $\cosh$ is just short-hand for $\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x})$. So, if you want to, just substitute that in this derivation and you'll get something that is a bit easier to grasp. Alternatively, you could also try proving some of the basic properties of $\cosh$, those can be picked up quite easily if you have familiarity with the exponential function.

Comment: Should be $2(e+e^{-1})$.

Comment: Integral of $\cosh x$ is. $\sinh x$. I get sharper result.

Comment: I like this solution. And this answers the question as one deduces:
$$
\frac{1}{e}+2 < 4 < I < 2\,(e-\tfrac{1}{e}) < 2\,e  < 2\,(e+\tfrac{1}{e})
$$

Comment: Yes, this is what a sharper estimate is.

Answer (score 2):

Use of MVT gives that there exist $x_0\in[0,1]$ such that
$$
I=\int_0^1 e^{x^3}+1/e^{x^3}\,dx=(1-0)(e^{x_0^3}+1/e^{x_0^3}).
$$
As $e^{x^3}+1/e^{x^3}$ is increasing, we get
$$1+1<I<e+1/e.$$
Since $e^{x^3}+1/e^{x^3}$ is convex we may reduce the upper bound by the triangle $(0,2)$, $(0,e+1/e)$, $(1,e+1/e)$, that is
$$1+1< I<\frac12(e+1/e) +1.$$